# Remove elements from the array which appear more than k times

Tags: python, brackets

This program gives out the output as

> 1 6 7 9 11

how can I make it give output as

> [1, 6, 7, 9, 11]

**Code:**

```
def RemoveElements(my_lst2, n, k): 

    mp = {i:0 for i in range(len(my_lst2))} 

    for i in range(n): 
        mp[my_lst2[i]] += 1

    for i in range(n): 
        if (mp[my_lst2[i]] <= 1): 

            print(my_lst2[i], end = " ",)
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    my_lst2 = [0,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,9,11,0,5]
    n = len(my_lst2)
    k = 2

RemoveElements(my_lst2, n, k)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are doing `print(my_lst2[i], end = " ",)` which prints it out as you currently have.  If you store the `my_lst2[i]` in a list and then print out that list, you will get what you want.

```
def RemoveElements(my_lst2, n, k):

    mp = {i:0 for i in range(len(my_lst2))}

    for i in range(n):
        mp[my_lst2[i]] += 1

    l = []

    for i in range(n):
        if (mp[my_lst2[i]] <= 1):
            l.append(my_lst2[i])

    print(l)
```